# How to get the duration, and then set it?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have videos `background.mp4` and `1.mp4`

I'm overlay `1.mp4` on `background.mp4`

```
ffmpeg -i background.mp4 -vf "movie=1.mp4[inner]; [in][inner] overlay [out]" completed.mp4
```

How to make the duration of `completed.mp4` was the same as `1.mp4`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i background.mp4 -vf "movie=1.mp4[inner];[in][inner]overlay=eof_action=endall[out]" completed.mp4
```

Comment: It does not work, the duration 'completed.mp4' = 'background.mp4'

Comment: Does background.mp4 have audio?

Comment: background.mp4 doesn't have audio.